# Pandas conditional based on columns and rows ouput to bool (replacing a `for` statement)

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a new column (bool) based on information encoded in multiple columns, but also the relative position of the index.

I have a DataFrame that has `start` and `end` columns, and a number of rows. I would like to keep rows that do not overlap with other rows, giving precedence to the highest row/first observation (DF is sorted).

In other words, if a range(start,end) is at least partially contained within a range(start,end) that has a lower index number, it will be assigned `False`. If no overlaps are found, it will be assigned `True`.

Here is a picture visually explaining what I am trying to do:
[image: viz_desc]

I have accomplished this using a for loop, but this is slow, even with modestly-sized DFs. I am looking for a more "pandas-y" way of filtering in order to have this run in <= O(n). This for loop approach drops the columns (ultimately what I am going to do) instead of creating a new column, but I imagine creating a new bool column is much easier with "for loop-less" approach. Here is the code I used to accomplish this:

```py
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(((5,12),(16,19),(7,14),(6,9),(17,18),(1,3)),columns=["start","end"])

dropIndexes=[]
for i in range(len(df) - 1, 0, -1):
    start=(df.iloc[i]['start'] >= df.iloc[list(range(0, i))][['start']]).start & (
           df.iloc[i]['start'] <= df.iloc[list(range(0, i))][['end']]).end    
    end  =(df.iloc[i]['end']   >= df.iloc[list(range(0, i))][['start']]).start & (
           df.iloc[i]['end']   <= df.iloc[list(range(0, i))][['end']]).end
    if True in (start|end).values: dropIndexes.append(i)
df=df.drop(dropIndexes)
df
```

This code goes from the "bottom up" in the DF and individually tests if first the current row's `start` value is contained between a `start` and `end` of any rows that have a lower index. It then repeats this for the current row's `end` value. It then tests if either the current `start` or `end` was contained within any other row with a lower index's range.

Comment: I know how to help you, but I am not sure I understand the intended logic for the task.

Comment: kindly explain ur logic. in simple terms.

Comment: @CeliusStingher updated for clarity

Comment: Why are iterating through the df in reverse order? Also, are there any negative values in the ```start``` and ```end``` columns?

Comment: I suppose in re-thinking about this, I didn't have to go bottom up, that is just how my brain parsed the problem. Should be the same either way though

Comment: (there are no negative values)

Comment: Adding for posterity: I am still working through the specifics here, but my question is (apparently) an interval tree question. eg: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ckingsf/bioinfo-lectures/intervaltrees.pdf I will update this when I come to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `start` and `end` columns do not have negative values.
You can make use of [pandas.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for your use-case.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(((5,12),(16,19),(7,14),(6,9),(17,18),(1,3)),columns=["start","end"])

start, end = -9999, -9999
def select_row(index_start, index_end):
    global start
    global end

    if start == -9999 and end == -9999:
        # case 1: initial case
        start = index_start
        end = index_end
        return True
    elif end < index_start:
        # case 2: towards the left
        end = index_end
        return True
    elif index_end < start:
        # case 3: towards the right
        start = index_start
        return True
    else:
        # case 4: overlapping
        return False

filt_index = df.apply(lambda row: select_row(row["start"], row["end"]), axis=1)
df = df.loc[filt_index, df.columns]
print(df)
```

P. S. I had to use `global` variables since I was getting `UnboundLocalError`. Also, I did not want to pass `start` and `end` as arguments to `apply()` for every row in the dataframe.

Comment: Does it help your use-case?

Comment: This did run much faster, but when I apply it to my data it does not behave as expected. It works with the toy data, but not with more complex data. I haven't fully grasped your algorithm yet, but I think something about storing values in `start` and `end` may be the issue (not necessarily because they are global)

Comment: It's probably failing for the edge cases. I don't have access to complete data, so I can't determine what edit to the answer will make it work for that data. However, can you replace ```end < index_start``` with ```end <= index_start``` and ```index_end < start``` with ```index_end <= start``` and see if that works?